# Connecting to mongoDB in spring boot causes errors

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot

I want to connect to mongoDB Atlas in a spring boot project, but always Exceptions are thrown. If I use Java without spring boot, everything works fine.
The following test project reproduces the errors.
The pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>maven-test</groupId>
<artifactId>test</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>


<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath />
</parent>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongodb-driver-sync</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongodb-driver-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

</project>
```

The Main-class:

```
package test;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.mongo.MongoDataAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.MongoAutoConfiguration;

@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {MongoAutoConfiguration.class, MongoDataAutoConfiguration.class})
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
    }

}
```

And the configuration for mongoDB:

```
package test;

import com.mongodb.ConnectionString;
import com.mongodb.MongoClientSettings;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClients;
import org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecRegistry;
import org.bson.codecs.pojo.PojoCodecProvider;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import static org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecRegistries.fromProviders;
import static org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecRegistries.fromRegistries;

@Configuration
public class MongoConfig {

    @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.uri}")
    private String connectionString;

    @Bean
    public MongoClient mongoClient() {
        System.out.println(this.connectionString);
        CodecRegistry pojoCodecRegistry = fromProviders(PojoCodecProvider.builder().automatic(true).build());
        CodecRegistry codecRegistry = fromRegistries(MongoClientSettings.getDefaultCodecRegistry(), pojoCodecRegistry);
        return MongoClients.create(MongoClientSettings.builder()
                                                      .applyConnectionString(new ConnectionString(connectionString))
                                                      .codecRegistry(codecRegistry)
                                                      .build());
    }
}
```

The uri for mongoDB is stored in application.properties.
If I start the server, the following exeception is thrown:

```
com.mongodb.MongoSocketWriteException: Exception sending message
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.translateWriteException(InternalStreamConnection.java:550) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.0.4.jar:na]
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:432) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.0.4.jar:na]
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendCommandMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:272) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.0.4.jar:na]
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendAndReceive(InternalStreamConnection.java:256) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.0.4.jar:na]
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.sendAndReceive(CommandHelper.java:83) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.0.4.jar:na]
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.executeCommand(CommandHelper.java:33) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.0.4.jar:na]
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initializeConnectionDescription(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:103) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.0.4.jar:na]
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initialize(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:60) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.0.4.jar:na]
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:128) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.0.4.jar:na]
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:117) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.0.4.jar:na]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_41]
```

Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty

So I have tried to disable ssl through adding to the uri: `&ssl=false`
However, then another exception is thrown:

```
com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.read(SocketStream.java:112) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.0.4.jar:na]
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveResponseBuffers(InternalStreamConnection.java:579) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.0.4.jar:na]
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:444) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.0.4.jar:na]
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveCommandMessageResponse(InternalStreamConnection.java:298) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.0.4.jar:na]
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendAndReceive(InternalStreamConnection.java:258) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.0.4.jar:na]
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.sendAndReceive(CommandHelper.java:83) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.0.4.jar:na]
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.executeCommand(CommandHelper.java:33) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.0.4.jar:na]
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initializeConnectionDescription(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:103) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.0.4.jar:na]
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initialize(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:60) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.0.4.jar:na]
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:128) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.0.4.jar:na]
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:117) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.0.4.jar:na]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_41]
```

I have found unfortunately no solution to solve them. Has someone encountered the same problem or knows a solution?
Thank you

Comment: Are you able to connect to the default `localhost:27017`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For everyone having the same problem: the cause was, that there were different versions in the maven repo. So mvn clean and mvn install solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me in August of 2019. I was able connect to mongoDB Atlas in a spring boot project.
But I used previous version of mongo driver 3.4.1. Now I can't test because I don't have atlas account anymore

```
    private void connect() {

    MongoClientURI uri = new MongoClientURI(
            "mongodb://myusername:mypass@mydatabase-shard-00-00-vawmn.mongodb.net:27017,mydatabase-shard-00-01-vawmn.mongodb.net:27017,mydatabase-shard-00-02-vawmn.mongodb.net:27017/test?ssl=true&replicaSet=MyDatabase-shard-0&authSource=admin&retryWrites=true&w=majority");

    MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(uri);
    DB database = mongoClient.getDB("mydb");
    DBCollection collection = database.getCollection("my_collection");
    DBCursor cur = collection.find();

    for (DBObject doc : cur) {
        DBObject name = (BasicDBObject) doc.get("name");
    }
}
```

And pom:

```
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- For Working with Json Web Tokens (JWT) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- For Java 8 Date/Time Support -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.springfox/springfox-swagger2 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.springfox/springfox-swagger-ui -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb/mongo-java-driver -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.1</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```